# Using Jinja2 for GitHub action

Tags: github, yaml, jinja2

Can I use Jinja2 to setup a GitHub action?

More specifically, is there a way to do something like:

```yaml
    {% for version in ["0.6.3", "0.5.0", "0.4.0", "0.3.0", "0.2.2"] %}
    - name: Check consistency with v{{ version }}
      if: runner.os == 'Linux'
      run: |
        conda install -c conda-forge python-gmatelastoplasticqpot={{ version }}
        python test/compare_versions/Cartesian2d_check_v{{ version }}.py
    {% endfor %}
```

(which raises an error)

Comment: Does this help https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-with-more-than-one-version-of-nodejs?

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε . Well... Partly. What I ask here is to loop *within* a job. What I understand from the docs is that it describes a loop *of* jobs